# Column cannot be converted from 'tinyint' to type 'int(12) unsigned in MySQL 5.6 replication

Tags: mysql, transactional-replication, mysql-5.6

I am having an issue in mysql 5.6 replication when trying to upgrade tinyint to int(12). I have upgraded a column at slave from tinyint(4) to int(12) and after a few minutes got below replication error :

> Column 9 of table 'mktplace.sales_order_item' cannot be converted from
>   type 'tinyint' to type 'int(12) unsigned'

Master has:

> binlog_format=MIXED

and above error occurs only for updates having row based binary log format.

FYI : MySQL version is exact same on both Master and slave i.e. 5.6.19-0ubuntu0.14.04.1-log and Table charset is similar too utf8.

Few lines of help would be really appreciable.

Comment: Have you got signed values in master-table (like -1)?

Comment: No, We only have unsigned values available.